# Problem with Quickly text input field

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, glade

## The Problem

I am using Quickly to try the mybrowser demo from the Ubuntu Website. 
Everything goes well until I add a simple text field (*for URL entry*) in Glade, then, no warnings are issued but the text-box will not allow text entry from the keyboard. text can be pasted into the field, but all keystrokes are ignored including the **Enter** key.

## The Questions

Does anyone know how to fix this, or suggest what I am doing that is causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Glade, select your entry and click the `Common` tab in the property editor on the right. Search for the `Can focus` property and make sure it's set to `True`.